# Enable zoom on UIImage but not for UIViews on top of the UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview, calayer

I have an imageview which is basically a picture of a map. I want to put markers on specific positions on this map(imageview) and also enable zooming animation to those markers.

I tried some CALayer manipulation but didn't really achieve anything.
Please help!

Comment: Can you add some code in order to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: So I have a static image of a map. I want to put small views which will basically behave like a marker on the map. I want this map to be zoomable but the marker should not zoom.

Comment: Are those markers of realtime coordinates, if so why don't you add annotations

Comment: I could just add the map as well as the markers inside a scroll view to achieve a zoom effect but then I zoom in the markers as well which I dont want. I just want the map to zoom.

Comment: @ChetanRajagiri No, the map itself is just an UIImageView and the markers just UIViews.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you will have to make a UIView and inside to have the UIImage from your map with equal size trailing etc.. 
then create an outlet from your UIView to to the ViewController and add programmatically new UIImageViews to the UIView that contains your Image with the map.

so the funcion that adds the new UIImageViews will be

```
func addSmallSubviewIntoParentView(){
        let tmpImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat))
        tmpImageView.image = yourImage
        viewOutlet.addSubview(tmpImageView)
    }
```

and add size and position based on parent UIView. 
Add constraints as you like.

But if you want to have an MKMapView you can disable user interaction and add MKAnnotationViews as you like to the CLLocation of the places

Comment: Adding the marker to the map is not what i am worried about. I want to know how I can achieve the zoom in effect without the markers being zoomed

Comment: If you add the markers to the MKMapView and on the delegate function func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? { } you have set the size of the image of the MKAnnotationView that you will insert it will not resizeand the map will zoom

Comment: The map is not a MKMapView. Its just an UIImage

Comment: can you please edit the post and add the code that you use for the zooming? it's just a math issue so that every time that the zoom func is called you will have to resize the pins.